# Center button in CSS

Tags: css, html, button, center

Trying to center a button with CSS. However, whenever I use display: block and margin: 0 auto; I get text decoration under the button text.

```
.app-download .btn {
   display: block;
   margin: 0 auto;
   text-decoration: none;
   text-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
   font-family: "News Cycle", sans-serif;
   font-size: 1.5em;
   border-radius: 5px;
   color: #ffffff;
   background: steelblue;
   width: 400px;
   padding: 20px 0;

}
.app-download .btn:hover {
  background: tomato;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

MY HTML

```
<div class="app-download">
    <div class="container">
          <a href="#"><button type="button" class="btn">Download for iPhone</button></a>
          <a href="#"><button type="button" class="btn">Download for Android</button></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I center the button without getting a text decoration underneath?

Comment: *Without* getting text decoration?

Answer (score 0):

Without your HTML, we can only guess at what you are doing here. But here's one possible solution:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style media="all">
.app-download {text-align: center;}
.app-download .btn {
   display: inline-block;
   text-decoration: none;
   text-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
   font-family: "News Cycle", sans-serif;
   font-size: 1.5em;
   border-radius: 5px;
   color: #ffffff;
   background: steelblue;
   width: 400px;
   text-align:center;
   padding: 20px 0;

}
.app-download .btn:hover {
  background: tomato;
  text-decoration: none;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="app-download">
    <a href="" class="btn">Button</a>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Here is a the problem i am having in JSFIDDLE http://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=EmpcAxzNcJ

Comment: I am trying to horizontally center the button within the div. whenever i add display and margin it adds a text decoration (underline)

Comment: O, right. In that case, add `text-align: center` to the container. (See updated code above.)

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your **CSS**

```
a
{
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

## [Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6Uy4U/1/)